# JTabbedPane ChangeListener

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane, changelistener

I need to detect when the selected tab changes, and get its index.

The following code works, but it fires the `println` as many times as the amount of tabs currently loaded:

```
tabbedPane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Tab: " + tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex());
        // Prints the string 3 times if there are 3 tabs etc
    }
});
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Check this: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing/tabbed_TpEvt.html Does it help you?

Comment: No, in fact it uses the same methods than my example

Comment: Sorry, but if you want to detect the id when the selected tab changes, don't you need to know where you have the ChangeEvent, with getSource() ? IMHO, maybe I'm wrong, the code prints out 3 times (if you have 3 tabs) because we don't know the "source" of event. How can you get the id of the selected tab changed when the code doesn't know what tab changed?

Comment: tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();

Comment: You are doing this in the correct way, and I also get multiple events. Is this a problem?

Comment: Some database action is linked to `stateChanged` so yes. I could use a counter so only the last event calls the mentioned DB method but maybe there's a clearer way?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

By JDK 6 Update 26 (Windows 7 64-Bit), I only get one event for the following demonstration code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 400);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    final JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    tabbedPane.addTab("One", new JPanel());
    tabbedPane.addTab("Two", new JPanel());
    tabbedPane.addTab("Three", new JPanel());
    tabbedPane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Tab: " + tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex());
        }
    });
    tabbedPane.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 400);
    frame.add(tabbedPane);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Can you figure out in the debugger why the listener is triggered three times?

Comment: Okay I'm stupid. The code that adds the `ChangeListener` is in the same block that adds a `Tab` so I was adding one listener per tab.

Answer (score 13):

for example

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class TestTabbedPane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JPanel ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(1, 1));
                JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.LEFT);
                jtp.addTab("Apple", new JLabel("Apple"));
                jtp.addTab("Banana", new JLabel("Banana"));
                jtp.addTab("Cherries", new JLabel("Cherries"));
                jtp.addTab("Grapes", new JLabel("Grapes"));
                ui.add(jtp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                jtp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
                jtp.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                        if (e.getSource() instanceof JTabbedPane) {
                            JTabbedPane pane = (JTabbedPane) e.getSource();
                            System.out.println("Selected paneNo : " + pane.getSelectedIndex());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }

    private TestTabbedPane() {
    }
}
```

printOut

```
run:
Selected paneNo : 1
Selected paneNo : 2
Selected paneNo : 3
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)
```