# How to detect/listen to a changed TabbedPane in Scala?

Tags: swing, scala, event-handling

**Background**

In this [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6803432/975129), I see that a change listener can be used on a `JTabbedPane` to detect the index `i` of the newly activated tab.

In the Scala docs, I can see that for a `TabbedPane` named `tp`, `tp.selection.index` will give me the `i` that I need, but how do I wire up the code to listen properly?

I tried following the `reactions-listenTo` paradigm that Scala seems to use, but ran into problems finding the appropriate event type.  If you click on [this link](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/scala-swing/index.html#scala.swing.event.Event) and click on *known subclasses*, there is a list of events that I can plug into reactions, but none of them seem to indicate TabChanged.

Below is my attempt to get this to work.

**CODE**

```
  private val tp = new TabbedPane() {
    pages += new TabbedPane.Page("Deck0",new ScrollPane(tables(0)))
    pages += new TabbedPane.Page("Deck1",new ScrollPane(tables(1)))

    reactions += {   // not sure what to put under reactions
      case e => println("%s => %s" format(e.getClass.getSimpleName, e.toString))
    }
  }
  listenTo( tp.selection )  // don't know if this is right
```

**UPDATE**

I have managed to google [the code for TabbedPane.scala](https://github.com/ingoem/scala-swing/blob/master/scala/swing/TabbedPane.scala).  The pertinent snippet is below - I'm trying to figure out the implications for my issue.

```
  /**
   * The current page selection
   */
  object selection extends Publisher {
    def page: Page = pages(index)
    def page_=(p: Page) { index = p.index }

    def index: Int = peer.getSelectedIndex
    def index_=(n: Int) { peer.setSelectedIndex(n) }

    peer.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener {
      def stateChanged(e: javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent) { 
        publish(SelectionChanged(TabbedPane.this))
      }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further researching the **UPDATE** that I added to the OP (source tells all) along with [this additional information](http://otfried-cheong.appspot.com/scala/index_31.html), I was able to work a solution simply:

```
import swing.event.SelectionChanged

private val tp = new TabbedPane() {
  pages += new TabbedPane.Page("Deck0",new ScrollPane(tables(0)))
  pages += new TabbedPane.Page("Deck1",new ScrollPane(tables(1)))
}

reactions += {
  case SelectionChanged( x ) => println( "changed to %d" format(tp.selection.index))
  case e => println("%s => %s" format(e.getClass.getSimpleName, e.toString))
}

listenTo( tp.selection )  // this is required
```

Comment: That's better. Not really intuitive; it just does not work the way you'd expect it to be.