# java jtabbedpane not firing changelistener

Tags: java, jtabbedpane, changelistener

I have a jtabbedpane and i'm trying to record when the tab is changed. i've tried using a change listener but it doesn't appear to be firing

```
        import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
        import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;

        tabbedPane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                JTabbedPane sourceTabbedPane = (JTabbedPane) e.getSource();
                int index = sourceTabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
                System.out.println("Tab changed to: " + index);
            }
        });
```

The code doesn't appear to be being called as the print isn't appearing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JTabbedPane ChangeListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799731/jtabbedpane-changelistener)

Comment: That one is asking for if its being fired multiple times, mines not being fired at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. There was a piece of code that was saving error messages to a file but it was also doing the same for normal output. Once that was changed the issue was resolved